# Adjective antonym of "discriminate"

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

In biology, hierarchical clustering is used to separate studied samples into different groups, thus if successful, the clustering criteria can be seen to "discriminate" between group A vs. B.

I am stuck trying to find an appropriate word to convey that two samples are so similar that they are "*indiscriminable*". It appears as that's not a word featured in dictionaries. I have tried "*indiscernable*" and that doesn't sound right either, neither does "*inseparable*".

What is a good adjective to use in this case? Should I try to rephrase my sentence?

---

PS: Please consider that this question refers to academic writing (in other words, "formal register" only).

Comment: *Indiscriminable* has certainly [been used](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=indiscriminable). It seems a good technical word.

Comment: What about "almost perfectly analogous"?

Comment: @rhetorician not sure if that would be clear enough to the audience of the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very likely looking for [indistinguishable](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indistinguishable):

> *adjective*
>   not able to be identified as different or distinct:
>   *the counterfeit bills were virtually indistinguishable from the real thing*

Comment: is there a nuance difference between "indiscriminable" and "indistinguishable"?

Comment: @posdef Perhaps not in practice. But _indiscriminable_ appears to be a word that people use because it sounds like it exists. Googling "hierarchical clustering indiscriminable" vs. "hierarchical clustering indistinguishable" should set the matter at rest.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer as it addresses the question as it stands. I wonder however if there is another word I can use (it appears as one of my references use exactly that phrasing which I would avoid to duplicate). Does *in-/non-discriminative* fit, seeing as *discriminative* seems to be adjective form of "discriminate"?

Comment: @posdef No, I don't think that they are proper or commonly used words. The fact that http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/discriminable is defined as being synonymous with _distinguishable_ further strengthens the case for _indistinguishable_.